# Limiting cell values in formulas

Tags: excel, max, cell, limit

I would like to use some kind of limit or over/under rule in a formula. The premise is if a number exceeds a certain value, then I only want to take that certain value. Here's an example:

If an employee's hours exceed 80 hours per month, only use 80 hours for accounting purposes. Let's say my employee Bob's timesheet looks like this:

Jan = 20 hours

Feb = 40 hours

Mar = 100 hours

Apr = 60 hours

etc.

If Bob gets paid $100/hours, then his final payment should be $100/hour * total hours works. Or in excel format, something like =100*sum(b1:b12) if hours are stored in column B.

BUT, I only want to take a Maximum of 80 hours each month... So the hours in the above example, as far as accounting is concerned, would look like this:

Jan = 20 hours

Feb = 40 hours

Mar = **80 hours**

Apr = 60 hours

etc.

I'd rather not build in another column for =if(b1>80,80,b1). And to be honest, it's bugging me now that I can't figure it out.

Please help!

Comment: You'll probably need a helper column, unless you want a VBA solution.  An idea is that you could use `Min` to determine the minimum hours. If your hours are in column B, in C, you can do `=min(80,b1)` which would return the smaller number, `80` or whatever the hours are in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this array formula:

```
=100 * SUM(IF(B1:B12>80,80,B1:B12))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode instead of Enter or Tab.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For a regular (non array) formula solution:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B4<80)*B1:B4+(B1:B4>=80)*80)
```